# Where to import other React component from if you are importing for Reacr component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have such folder hierarchy:

```
src/
    components.tsx
    components/
    anyComponent.tsx
    anyComponent1.tsx
```

`components.tsx` is the entry point:

```
export { Input } from './components/Input';
export { Label } from './components/Label';
export { Textarea } from './components/Textarea';
export { RadioButton } from './components/RadioButton';
export { ModernRadioButton } from './components/ModernRadioButton';
export { ModernRadioButtonGroup } from './components/ModernRadioButtonGroup';
```

What should I write in my `anyComponent1.tsx` that is located in the **components** folder?

1. `import { anyComponent } from './anyComponent';`
2. `import { anyComponent } from '../components';` (entry point)

Comment: `import { anyComponent } from './anyComponent';`

Comment: @jabaa Are there any reasons why should I use exactly this variant?

Comment: A child component shouldn't know about its parent component but it can know its siblings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Result: Error. Dependency cycle detected.

Component1.tsx:

```
import { Button } from '../components';
```

components.tsx:

```
export { Button } from './components/Button';
export { Component1 } from './components/Component1.tsx
```

---

### Result: Everything is fine.

`components.tsx` entry point is used for non-component files, for example `App.tsx`.
Component1.tsx:

```
import { Button } from './Button';
```

components.tsx:

```
export { Button } from './components/Button';
export { Component1 } from './components/Component1';
```